# How to show the contacts like messaging screen in android?

Tags: android

i want to show the name and number of the person stored in contact list like the messaging screen in android mobile.see this link http://imgur.com/dErrn. I want to do like this in my application.How we can do like this? I retrieved the contacts using `ContactsContract`. Iam showing the contacts in `AutoCompleteTextView`,but its showing the number only.I want to have identical drop down like the link i attached with the name and the number. Please help me if anybody know about this.

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should override the AutoCompleteTextView Drop down list item

Answer (score 0):

You should read the source code for the messaging application. This will help you understand how its being done. This is freely available on the AOSP source code.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look over [AutoCompleteTextView.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)